# Error while trying to use a parameter in function

Tags: javascript, symfony, routes

Working on symfony, I'm developping the following javascript function using bootbox :

```
function ask_delete(id)
{
    bootbox.confirm("Are you sure?", function(result) {
        if(result)
        {
            document.location.href = "{{ path('SomethingBundle_delete', {'id': id}) }}";
        }
    }); 
}
```

I'd like to catch my id parameter and pass it as argument to my "SomethingBundle_delete" route.
However it seems that id is not defined. Do you know how I could pass it as argument ?

Answer (score 4):

The `id` value is available but you need to reference it as a value not as a string literal

```
"{{ path('SomethingBundle_delete', {'id': " + id + "}) }}"
```

Comment: Oups sorry I was too fast ^^ My paramater value was not the id but the string "+id+" I don't think it solves the problem.

Comment: The `id` may be available like that, but it makes little to no sense to assign that value to `document.location.href`, when in essence it is a server-side expression (a template method call).

Answer (score 0):

You need to get a better understanding of what happens server-side and client-side. Your `ask-delete` function is called client-side, and thus the `id` does not have a value that you can use for a server-side resolution of the route path, eg:

```
document.location.href = "{{ path('SomethingBundle_delete', {'id': id}) }}";
```

Is where your misunderstanding takes place. The `path` function is a template function that takes place **server-side**, way before `id` is ever assigned a value/comes into scope.

To solve the problem you need to change your code to something like this:

```
document.location.href = "/route/path/for/your/" + id;
```

The most important lesson here is understanding the nature of the client-server architecture that is your web-application (and any web-application for that matter).

Answer (score 0):

maybe [FOSJsRoutingBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle) can help you.

use

```
Routing.generate('your_route',{id:id});
```